# How can I change repository mirrors using prompt?

Tags: package-management, updates

I tried to update my Linux Mint to "Virginia", the new version that is recently released.
It asked me to update some packages. But I got the following error:

`Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (IP address), connection timed out`

I restarted but I couldn't login getting the following error:

`unable to launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon`

I tried the following commands in the command line (Ctrl+Alt+F2) to fix the problem:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nemo`

`sudo apt-get install cinnamon`

But it doesn't work keep getting `Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (IP address), connection timed out` error.

I thought by changing the repository mirrors maybe I can fix the problem.

I don't have any snapshot to restore. I only have access to the command line.

How can I fix the problem? If I could move some of my files I'm willing to remove the Linux and install a new one.

Comment: Mint is off topic on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: askubuntu.com is supporting Ubuntu and its official flavors, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic for details. Mint is not a flavor of Ubuntu but a Linux Distribution on its own. You may want to raise your question in a forum dedicated to Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to a different repository mirror if you're having trouble connecting to **archive.ubuntu.com**. Here's a list of available Ubuntu mirrors: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors.

To update the mirror in your system:

Open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file in a text editor with root privileges. For example, you can use nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In this file, find lines that contain **archive.ubuntu.com** and replace them with your chosen mirror address. For example, if you're choosing **mirror.5i.fi**, it would look something like this:

```
deb https://mirror.5i.fi/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
```

After making these changes, don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update` to refresh your package list.

Another thing you can do is to execute the following command and update your post with [Edit] with the output of the command:

```
traceroute archive.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I used a combination what you suggested and solutions in other topics.